# Permisson denied to open liteloader-1.7.2.jar

Tags: jar, terminal, minecraft

I was downloading a mod for minecraft. Although it is not excutable so I put in ( chmod +x liteloader-1.7.2.jar ) but after that it has a lock on it. So I clicked on it and it said

error:  cannot open zipfile [ /home/family/Desktop/liteloader-1.7.2.jar ]
          Permission denied 
zipinfo:  cannot find or open /home/family/Desktop/liteloader-1.7.2.jar, /home/family/Desktop/liteloader-1.7.2.jar.zip or /home/family/Desktop/liteloader-1.7.2.jar.ZIP.

Permission  denied!   Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to grant administration privileges using the sudo command!

So basically:

```
sudo chmod +x yourfile.jar
```

Comment: ... I tryed it will not open. still.

Comment: try this:
    java -jar yourfile.jar

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it in the terminal with java, try running it with this command: `java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -jar /home/family/Desktop/liteloader-1.7.2.jar`
Note that the `Xmx` and `Xms` set the amount of memory Minecraft gets to use.